# How to use White-test to check if the heteroscedasticity has been effectively dealt with by a WLS?

Tags: regression, least-squares, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression, white-test

Consider an OLS model with $n$ observations and $p$ explanatory variables (including an intercept term)
$$y=X\beta + \epsilon$$
We may use a White test to (approximately) check for the presence of heteroscedasticity on an $\alpha$-significance level, by conducting an auxiliary regression:
$$e = Y\gamma + \eta$$
where $e=y-X\widehat\beta$ ($\widehat\beta$ is the OLS estimator of $\beta$) and $Y$ is the matrix of all the auxiliary regression variables $1, X_i, X_i\odot X_j$. The Lagrange multiplier statistic $nR^2$ of this auxiliary regression is then compared against $\chi_\alpha^2(p)$. If $nR^2>\chi_\alpha^2(p)$, the null hypothesis that $\epsilon$ is homoscedastic is rejected.

Now suppose we *believe* $\epsilon$ is heteroscedastic with $\Bbb V(\epsilon\mid X) = \Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Then we may use a WLS model to reestimate the original OLS by specifying the weight $W:=\Lambda^{-1}$, and premultiply the original model by $W^{1/2}$ to obtain
$$W^{1/2}y=W^{1/2}X\beta+W^{1/2}\epsilon$$
and the WLS estimator of $\beta$ which is an OLS estimator of $\beta$ under the transformed model should be
$$\widehat\beta_{W}=(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy.$$
**Question**: how do we use a White test to measure how accurately $W$ has captured the real heteroscedasticity structure?

A naive thought would be just using the WLS residual $e_W:=y-X\widehat\beta_W$ and the original $Y$ as the inputs for the White test. However, it is evident that 
$$\Bbb E(\widehat\beta_W)=(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TW\Bbb E(y)=(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWX\beta=\beta=\Bbb E(\widehat\beta)$$
so $\widehat\beta_W$ usually shouldn't deviate too much from $\widehat\beta$, and thus $e_W$ won't be much different from $e$. Hence such a way of "White test" can tell little about how well $\Bbb V(\epsilon\mid X)$ is addressed by $W$.

Another more plausible thought is consider the transformed model instead of the original OLS model, i.e. use the weighted residual $W^{1/2}e_W$ for the auxiliary regression. But when it comes to choosing the explanatory variables we'll have a problem: should we choose the original $Y$ (spanned by zero, first and second degree terms of $X$)? It seems weird matching $W^{1/2}e_W$. So a more natural idea would be matching $e_W$ with $W^{1/2}X$. But wait, there's no longer an intercept term in $W^{1/2}X$, and there seems to be no way to naturally construct auxiliary variables from $W^{1/2}X$ without introducing a new dof..

**So how is this done in reality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you know $W$, then let $Y_{new} = W^{1/2}Y$ and $X_{new} = W^{1/2}X$. Then forget about $Y$ and $X$. Go back to use $Y_{new}$ and $X_{new}$ to perform OLS, to use a White test to (approximately) check for the presence of heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Thanks but my problem lie exactly in **how** to use X_new for the White test? The original intercept term is lost when premultiplied by $W^{1/2}$, and if we "forcefully" introduce a new intercept term, well, we effectively introduce a new dof in $X_{new}$....

Comment: How do you lost intercept? In addition, white test does not require intercept. Suppose you have a intercept and 4 slopes in the Y-X model. In your new model $Y_{new}-X_{new}$, you still have 5 regression coefficients, right?

Comment: $W^{1/2}X$ no longer has an intercept column (the initial intercept column in $X$ is turned into a non constant column namely varies with rows).

Comment: It is OK, just use $X_{new}$ . The number of columns in $X_{new}$ and $X$ are the same. The first column of $X$ is 1, and the first column of $X_{new}$ is not only 1. But it does not matter.

Comment: actually it does matter. Theoretically, White test requires an intercept to be used. Also if I only pass $X_{new}$ to the white test function of a statistical package (say Python statsmodels.api) then an Error occurs saying the model dof doesn't match with the rank of $Y_{new}$.

Comment: I think that is software problem. The White test needs: 1) square of residual, 2) original covariates, 3) square of original covariates, 4)cross product of the covariates. Then regression 1) on 2), 3), and 4). Finally check $nR^2$. I cannot find in which step we cannot go through when $X_{new} $ and $Y_{new}$ are used.

Comment: sorry but by definition white test needs an intercept term. This causes a problem when you want to specify the covariates in this case: the covariates must include an intercept which is now absent from $X_{new}$. So we must add an intercept term to $X_{new}$, but this would add a dof. So it seems to me using $X_{new}$ directly is not the right way to go.

Comment: Where did you find that intercepts is required?

Comment: the intercept term is present in the auxiliary regression in White's original paper. But you're right: we should just use *all* of the second order terms of Xnew and then add *one* intercept, and the increase of dof is totally normal here.  Also there  may be a problem with the statistical package.

Comment: If you have package to perform regression, it is not hard to manipulate the data (generate the necessary variables), fit the regression model and check the $R^2$. Is Answer acceptable?

Comment: I don't think it's remediable for the function I'm using now ([`statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_white`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/sandbox/stats/diagnostic.html#het_white) in Python). It basically requires your auxiliary explanatory variables must contain at least one intercept term, and you cannot manually add the intercept outside the interface.

Comment: So, there is a way to manually implement the White estimator in the transformed model. The question is, do we know it actually converge to the chi-squared distribution so that we can interpret the resulting p value correctly, as in the standard White test? In other words, does it make sense to use the White test here? I'm having a hard time finding that answer.